Counting number of cells populated with data based on referenced dates in the future
I am looking for a formula that will COUNT the number of cells in a row that:
a. Is populated with data
b. Is in the same column as a date that takes place in the future (after today's date)
In the example below, the expected result is 3 since there are 3 cells that are populated and also are in columns with corresponding dates that happen in the future.  The populated cells with dates in the past are ignored in the count.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

In the increasing order of insanity:
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:K1>NOW())*(B2:K2<>""))
=COUNTIFS(B1:K1, ">" & NOW(), B2:K2, "<>")
=SUM(IF((B1:K1>NOW())*(B2:K2<>""), 1, 0))
=COUNTA(FILTER(B2:K2, (B1:K1>NOW())*(B2:K2<>"")))
=MMULT(N(B1:K1>NOW()), TRANSPOSE(N(B2:K2<>"")))
=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("B1:K1")>NOW(), IF(INDIRECT("B2:K2")<>"", 1, 0), 0))



Count With Multiple Conditions

This is similar to the case in your previous question with the key difference that since you're counting, you could multiply only the conditions and sum up the resulting array.
There are many ways to do it so don't discard the possibilities covered in the other answers. Each of them may be considered a lesson on its own.

Condition 1

Assuming that all values in the first row are dates (not dates with times formatted as dates), you could get away with:
B1:K1>TODAY()


Since TODAY() means e.g. 7/12/2024 0:00 AM, and if somehow a time could slip in those dates, the following condition would be more accurate (meaning "starting with tomorrow"):
B1:K1>=TODAY()+1


If you'll be copying the formula down you'll want to lock ($) the row:
B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1



Condition 2

Looking at your screenshot, it seems that you're looking for numbers in the second row:
=ISNUMBER(B2:K2)


If your condition should be all populated cells, you could use:
=NOT(ISBLANK(B2:K2))


But that will include cells containing Nothing (e.g. cells whose formula evaluates to Nothing (e.g. ="") or such cells copied as values). To exclude those cells, use one of the following (usually the 1st):
=B2:K2<>""
=LEN(B2:K2)>0



The Formula

Now multiply the conditions inside SUMPRODUCT (Legacy Excel) or SUM (Excel versions that support Dynamic Arrays):
=SUMPRODUCT((B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1)*ISNUMBER(B2:K2))
=SUM((B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1)*ISNUMBER(B2:K2))

In older versions of Excel, you can use SUM but you have to confirm the formula by holding down Ctrl+Shift and pressing Enter (aka CSE).


Errors

If you're expecting errors in any of the rows and you don't want to include those, you could 'slip in' an IFERROR to avoid 'breaking' the formula:
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1)*ISNUMBER(B2:K2),0))
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1)*(B2:K2<>""),0))

Since ISNUMBER already covers excluding errors for the 2nd row, use the more accurate:
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(B$1:K$1>=TODAY()+1,0)*ISNUMBER(B2:K2))



Related

In my answer to your previous question, the crucial ISNUMBER condition wasn't used because the multiplication of the numbers in the 2nd row and the date condition (of the 1st row) inside the IFERROR already covered it (anything that's not a number multiplied by a number will result in an error).


Give a try to
=COUNTIFS(Daterange,">"&TODAY(),ValueRange,"<>")


Following Michal's lead, adding a couple more, for fun:
=LET(
    dates_and_data, $B$1:$AA$100,
    data, INDEX(dates_and_data, ROW(), ),
    dates, INDEX(dates_and_data, ROW() - 1, ),
    SUM((LEN(TRIM(data)) > 0) * (dates > NOW()))
)


Addressing indirectly with (off putting) OFFSET:
=LET(
    max_items, 100,
    dates_and_data, OFFSET(
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),
        -1,
        1,
        2,
        max_items
    ),
    data, INDEX(dates_and_data, ROW(), ),
    dates, INDEX(dates_and_data, ROW() - 1, ),
    SUM((LEN(TRIM(data)) > 0) * (dates > NOW()))
)


